# Do I need an IDP in Sweden?

Tags: automobiles, sweden, rental, denmark

I'm a 23 old guy from Saudi Arabia, I will be in Sweden this August, I'm looking to rent a car from Malmo to go to Denmark, anyhow my friend says that since my Saudi license is in English I won't need an IDP , Does that also apply for Denmark ?

Comment: Here are [the Swedish requirements](https://www.transportstyrelsen.se/sv/vagtrafik/Korkort/har-korkort/utlandska-korkort/). Seems like it would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

One rental company may require the IDP translation, while another rental company may not.

[This Danish government webpage](https://www.fstyr.dk/DA/Korekort/Ombytning-af-udenlandsk-korekort/Ansog-om-ombytning/Engelsk-version-af-ans%C3%B8g.aspx) (it's in English) addresses getting a Danish license if one becomes a Danish resident. However, language at the bottom of the page suggests that a foreign license with English text might be acceptable for tourists. Here's a screenshot of the relevant text:

[image]